# Really bad libgdx performance after porting to iOS

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx, robovm

I've got a my first libgdx game completed on Android and I've been trying to port it over to iOS. I've tried both MobiDevelop RoboVM and Intel Multi-OS Engine. The game seems to run okay on the simulator, but on device (iPhone 5) it's absolutely unplayable.

[Here's an example just on the main menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjDSN.jpg)

Buttons are ImageButtons added to the stage

```
_imgPlayButtonUnpressed = new TextureRegion(assetManager.get("img/button_resume_unpressed.png", Texture.class));
_imgPlayButtonPressed = new TextureRegion(assetManager.get("img/button_resume_pressed.png", Texture.class));
_buttonPlay = new ImageButton(new TextureRegionDrawable(_imgPlayButtonUnpressed), new TextureRegionDrawable(_imgPlayButtonPressed));
```

Buttons are animated by doing some math and calling setBounds in render()

```
    if (_animIntervals % 2 == 0) {
        width = Animation.easeOutCubic(_animTime, Constants.BUTTON_LARGE_WIDTH, 30, Constants.ANIM_BUTTON_PULSE_INTERVAL);
        x = Animation.easeOutCubic(_animTime,(Constants.VIRTUAL_WIDTH - Constants.BUTTON_LARGE_WIDTH) / 2,  -15, Constants.ANIM_BUTTON_PULSE_INTERVAL);
        y = Animation.easeOutCubic(_animTime, 450, -15, Constants.ANIM_BUTTON_PULSE_INTERVAL);
    } else {
        width = Animation.easeInOutCubic(_animTime, Constants.BUTTON_LARGE_WIDTH + 30, -30, Constants.ANIM_BUTTON_PULSE_INTERVAL);
        x = Animation.easeInOutCubic(_animTime, ((Constants.VIRTUAL_WIDTH - Constants.BUTTON_LARGE_WIDTH) / 2) - 15, 15, Constants.ANIM_BUTTON_PULSE_INTERVAL);
        y = Animation.easeInOutCubic(_animTime, 450 - 15, 15, Constants.ANIM_BUTTON_PULSE_INTERVAL);
    }

    _parent.batch.draw(_imgTransparentOverlay, (Constants.VIRTUAL_WIDTH - Constants.BUTTON_LARGE_WIDTH) / 2, 450, width + 15, width + 15);

    _buttonPlay.setBounds(x, y, width, width);
```

Squares in the background are drawn using SpriteBatch

```
private TextureRegion _imgRed;    
...

_imgRed = new TextureRegion(assetManager.get("img/normal_red.png", Texture.class));
...

for (int i = 0; i < Constants.BOARD_MENU_SIZE_X; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Constants.BOARD_MENU_SIZE_Y; ++j) {
        Square s = _board.getSquare(i, j);
        if (s.getType() == Square.Type.Corrupted) {
            block = _imgRed;
        } else if (s.getType() == Square.Type.Defragmented) {
            block = _imgGreen;
        } ...

        float imgX = SQUARES_INITIAL.x + i * Board.BLOCK_TOTAL_WIDTH;
        float imgY = SQUARES_INITIAL.y + j * Board.BLOCK_TOTAL_WIDTH;

        _parent.batch.draw(block, imgX, imgY, Board.getBlockWidth(), Board.getBlockWidth());
    }
}
```

Any clues or tips on what to look out for?

Comment: maybe TextureAtlas all your 2d assets? Probably not the cause, but could improve both platforms and get your more information about the root cause.

Comment: I actually just did this as someone on reddit also suggested it.  Checked my SpriteBatch render calls per frame and it went down from 400+ to 5! 
 Definitely did improve performance and it's noticeable on Android - but iOS remains just as slow as before.

Comment: Also tried using ShapeRenderer as well

Comment: hmmmmMMMMm well I would perhaps strip down the app further and further, testing as you go until you get to the libgdx base application. If even the libgdx base application has the ios slowdown, I'd check the underlying ios conversion tool and version. And if at some point as you strip down ios performance comes back, that gives you a big clue and would be valuable info for the libgdx core devs.

Comment: Hello, did you ever fix your issue. I'm having similar challenges as well, with my iOS game stuttering at times and crashing at other times